# jquery autocomplete function add field

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to alter some autocomplete code that was given to me.  The existing code automatically fills in a persons address, after selecting a person.  I want to alter it to automatically fill in the address AND insert a custom field.  Below are the changes I have made to the code to attempt this.  I am looking for a working example of how to "auto fill" multiple items using this code, or a link to a tutorial.

autocomplete code :

```
$('#clientCompanyName').autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'ajax.php',
            dataType: "json",
            method: 'post',
            data: {
                name_startsWith: request.term,
                type: 'customerName'
            },
            success: function( data ) {

                if(!data.length){
                    var result = [
                      {
                          label: 'No Client found', 
                          value: ''
                      }
                    ];
                    response(result);
                }else{
                    response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                        var code = item.split("|");
                            return {
                                label: code[1],
                                value: code[1],
                                data : item
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                }



            });
    },
    autoFocus: true,            
    minLength: 1,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        if( typeof ui.item.data !== "undefined" ){
            var names = ui.item.data.split("|");
            $(this).val(names[1]);
            getClientAddress(names[0]);
            // Added getClientField2(names[0]);
            $('#client_id').val( names[0] );
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }               
});
function getClientAddress(id){

     $.ajax({
         url: "ajax.php",
         method: 'post', 
         data:{id:id, type:'clientAddress'},
         success: function(result){
            $("#clientAddress").html(result);
        }
     });
}
//added function getClientField2(id){

     $.ajax({
         url: "ajax.php",
         method: 'post', 
         data:{id:id, type:'clientField2'},
         success: function(result){
            $("#clientField2").html(result);
        }
     });
}
```

Server Code :

```
if(isset($_POST['type']) && $_POST['type'] == 'clientAddress' ){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $query = "SELECT id, addressLine1 FROM customers WHERE id =$id";
    $result = mysqli_query($db->con, $query);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $address = '';
    if(!empty( $data )){
        $address = isset($data['addressLine1'])? $data['addressLine1'].' &#13;' : '';
    }
    mysqli_close($db->con);
    echo $address;exit;
}
if(isset($_POST['type']) && $_POST['type'] == 'clientField2' ){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $query = "SELECT id, field2 FROM customers WHERE id =$id";
    $result = mysqli_query($db->con, $query);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $field2 = '';
    if(!empty( $data )){
        $field2 = isset($data['field2'])? $data['field2'].' &#13;' : '';
    }
    mysqli_close($db->con);
    echo $field2;exit;
}
```

Comment: "Not working" is not a problem description. Please add a [mcve].

Comment: @АндрейБеньковский Sorry for the lack of explanation.  I commented out the code to show what I added, and am not sure what more to add.  I am brand new to javascript/jquery, and am looking for a tutorial to teach me how to do this, more than anything